# How to get namespace of xml file by prefix (groovy)

Tags: xml, groovy, namespaces

I found tons of examples how to add namespace to xml file but nothing how to get one from existing file. I'm using XmlParser.
To be clear, if I have a file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
...
</wsdl>
```

and I have prefix `soap` then I want to get `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/` as a result

When I use:

```
def wsdlRoot = new XmlParser().parseText(text)
println wsdlRoot.attribute('xmlns:soap')
println wsdlRoot.@'xmlns:soap'
```

I get

```
null 
null
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

- Using `XmlSlurper` and not making namespace unaware.

Eg;

```
def wsdlRoot = new XmlSlurper().parseText( text )
assert wsdlRoot.lookupNamespace( 'soap' ) == 
       'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
```

- Using `XmlParser` and making namespace unaware

Eg;

```
def wsdlRoot = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(xml)
assert wsdlRoot.@'xmlns:soap' == 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
```

I suppose first approach would be preferable for you.